# AddWithValue doesn't work when updating records

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have this code

```
    MySQL_Query = "UPDATE `owner_info` " _
    & "SET first_name=" & first_name _
    & ", last_name= " & last_name _
    & ", middle_name=" & middle_name _
    & ", address= " & address _
    & ", contact_num= " & contact_num _
    & " WHERE id=" & ownerID

    Console.WriteLine(MySQL_Query)

    Dim MySQL_CMD As New MySqlCommand(MySQL_Query, MysqlConn)
    With frmOwner_Edit
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(first_name) = True Then first_name = .lblExisting_FirstName.Text
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(last_name) = True Then last_name = .lblExisting_LastName.Text
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(middle_name) = True Then middle_name = .lblExisting_MiddleName.Text
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(address) = True Then address = .lblExisting_Address.Text
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(contact_num) = True Then contact_num = .lblExisting_ContactNum.Text
    End With
    Try
        MySQL_CMD.Connection.Open()
        'MySQL_CMD.CommandText = MySQL_Query
        MySQL_CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        Console.WriteLine("Error: Owner Info Insert")
        Console.WriteLine(myerror)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Close()
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
```

and it is **working perfectly**, I am trying to apply AddWithValue but it doesn't work? I feel that I am missing something here. Here's the code.

```
    MySQL_Query = "UPDATE `owner_info` " _
    & "SET first_name='@first_name', last_name='@last_name', middle_name='@middle_name', address='@address', contact_num='@contact_num' " _
    & "WHERE id='@id'"
    Dim MySQL_CMD As New MySqlCommand(MySQL_Query, MysqlConn)
    With frmOwner_Edit
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(first_name) = True Then first_name = .lblExisting_FirstName.Text
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(last_name) = True Then last_name = .lblExisting_LastName.Text
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(middle_name) = True Then middle_name = .lblExisting_MiddleName.Text
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(address) = True Then address = .lblExisting_Address.Text
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(contact_num) = True Then contact_num = .lblExisting_ContactNum.Text
    End With
    Try
        MySQL_CMD.Connection.Open()
        MySQL_CMD.CommandText = MySQL_Query
        MySQL_CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", first_name)
        MySQL_CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", last_name)
        MySQL_CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middle_name", middle_name)
        MySQL_CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address)
        MySQL_CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact_num", contact_num)
        MySQL_CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ownerID)
        MySQL_CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        Console.WriteLine("Error: Owner Info Insert")
        Console.WriteLine(myerror)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Close()
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Comment: Your params are not in your query... You need to include each one into the query string.. Replace all your strings with the correct param for each.

Comment: Ow, wait I'll edit my question. I have that already sorry for not including it

Comment: Remove the ticks...Your enclosing your params you can't do that. It works fine when not using params but when you do you do not include them.

Comment: You mean like this? `first_name=@first_name`

Comment: Oh, so simple! It's working now. I don't know why I didn't tried that before. I've been stuck here for more than 2 1/2 hours! Please add an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: In addition, don't use `AddWithValue` for adding the parameters (it's a bad practice that leads to poor parameter typing). [Use .Add instead](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Thank you @Alejandro! Yeah `.Add` is much better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the ticks around your params. When they are there `MySql` treats them as strings and not parameters. So the error would be from not supplying the params it would need.